# Chromatic polynomial of complete bipartite graph

Tags: polynomials, graph-theory, coloring, bipartite-graphs

I need to compute the chromatic polynomial of a complete bipartite graph. I know that the chromatic polynomial of a complete graph is $\chi(G)= k(k-1)\dots(k-n+1)$. How can I extend this solution to a complete bipartite graph without using surjections or Stirling numbers.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What makes you think that there is a formula without Stirling numbers?

Comment: The fact that we did not have it in class yet, so I doubt that I can use it to compute the polynomial.

Comment: I mean, you could certainly start with the formula using Stirling numbers, then replace expressions of the form $\{{a \atop b}\}$ by the inclusion-exclusion based identity, and get a double sum. You could even explain what they are without using the word "surjection", if you really wanted, though that's a weird constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Is there also a derivation that shows how we computed this polynomial?